# how can I search data in set of columns with spaces in their names (ex- iron[space]man)

Tags: vb.net

I want to search for a keyword on 4 columns like :

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
con=new OleDbConnection (connectionstring)
cmd=new OleDbCommand (Select * from DVD_INFO where slot 1 = ' "+TXTSearch .Text+" ' OR slot 2 = ' "+TXTSearch .Text+" ' ...etc)
con.open ()
dr=cmd.ExecuteReader

While dr.read
  txtDVDno.Text = dr ("DVD no")
End While

con.Close ()
```

Error Message
syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Slot 1 = 'Iron Man"

MsgName is  OleDbException was Unhandled

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names with spaces should be enclosed in square brackets

```
cmd=new OleDbCommand (Select * from DVD_INFO where [slot 1] = ....."
```

Said that, start as soon as possible to use a parameterized query to avoid sql injection security problems and parsing problems

```
Dim cmdText = "Select * from DVD_INFO where [slot 1] = @search" 
Using con=new OleDbConnection (connectionstring)
using cmd=new OleDbCommand (cmdText, con)
    con.open()
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@search", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TXTSearch.Text
    Using dr=cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.read
            txtDVDno.Text = dr("DVD no")
        End While
    End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Note that if you want to repeat the search on other fields you need to add another parameter for each condition also if it is the same value repeated more than one time. This is necessary with OleDb because this driver is not able to recognize the parameters by their placeholder name. It uses a strictly positional order and so, if you have two where condition you need to add two parameters to the collection no matter what is their name or value.

**EDIT**
If you want to execute the search having only a partial text you could use the `LIKE` operator in your query text and change the way in which you initialize the parameters adding the wildcard symbol `%`

```
Dim cmdText = "Select * from DVD_INFO where [slot 1] LIKE @search" 
....

cmd.Parameters.Add("@search", OleDbType.VarWChar). Value = TXTSearch.Text & "%"
```

Of course the wildcard character could be added at the beginning of the searched text to give different meanings to your search text (field begins, ends, contains)